# Debugging Application on Raspberry pi with KDevelop

Tags: c++, gdb, kdevelop

I have an application which runs on the Raspberry Pi and I would like to debug it from my host computer.

Cross compiling works fine and I am able to start the gdb server to debug.
[image]

**gdbConfigurationScript.sh**

empty!

**copyToRemote.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
USER=pi
HOST_IP=192.168.178.20
REMOTE_IP=multikopter
TARGET_PATH=/home/pi/Documents/Multikopter
PROGRAM=Multikopter
PORT=12345
PATH_TO_PROGRAM_HOST="/home/martin/GITProjekte/Build00_Multikopter"
PW=****

if [ -f "$PATH_TO_PROGRAM_HOST/$PROGRAM" ]
then
    echo "Copy file '$PATH_TO_PROGRAM_HOST/$PROGRAM' to target"
    sshpass -p $PW ssh -t $USER@$REMOTE_IP "echo PGREPGDBSERVER: $(pgrep gdbserver);sudo kill -2 $(pgrep gdbserver)"
    sshpass -p $PW scp "$PATH_TO_PROGRAM_HOST/$PROGRAM" $USER@$REMOTE_IP:$TARGET_PATH
    sshpass -p $PW ssh -t $USER@$REMOTE_IP "sudo gdbserver $HOST_IP:$PORT $TARGET_PATH/$PROGRAM"
else
    echo "file '$PATH_TO_PROGRAM_HOST/$PROGRAM'not exist"
fi
```

**connectToRemoteGDB.sh**

```
file Multikopter
target remote multikopter:12345
b main
continue
```

The problem is, I'm not able to stop the program again and the gdbserver is still running. To debug again, I have to kill the gdbserver on the raspberrypi manually first.

Is there another way to debug remote with KDevelop or is there an easy way to stop the program?

Comment: `sudo pkill -9 gdbserver` instead of `kill -2`? Also, why is your program running as root?

Comment: Unrelated: consider using SSH public keys so you don't have to futz around with `sshpass`.

Comment: For more details see kill(1).
Usage:
 kill [options] <pid> [...]

Options:
 <pid> [...]            send signal to every <pid> listed
 -<signal>, -s, --signal <signal>
                        specify the <signal> to be sent
 -l, --list=[<signal>]  list all signal names, or convert one to a name
 -L, --table            list all signal names in a nice table

 -h, --help     display this help and exit
 -V, --version  output version information and exit

Comment: `sudo pkill -9 gdbserver`. Note the "p" there.

Comment: Thank you for the proposal with the public keys. When I am trying sudo pkill -9 gdbserver it does not work. gdbserver is not killed, and I am not able to restart.

Comment: Sorry I copied the wrong: Copy file '/Build00_Multikopter/Multikopter' to target
    Connection to multikopter closed.
    Process /Multikopter created; pid = 1775
    Listening on port 12345
But I am not able to press the continue button in KDevelop to start the program.

Comment: But the problem is also that gdbserver is closed when I debug newly. When I stop with KDevelop, The motors of the copter are still running, because gdb is not ended.

Comment: That is correct. `gdbserver` remains running because you might attach to it later. If you want it to stop you need to convince KDevelop to give a `monitor exit` command somehow. Might be in the settings?

Comment: But KDevelop should do that when I press the stop button. Or this different?